# Как отметить первый элемент в списке (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Для того чтобы автоматически выбрать первый элемент в списке можно исполжьзовать

```
this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

но эта этот метод выбирает и переходит в следующую форму. А как просто отметить элемент и все.

Comment: У вас обработчик SelectedIndexChanged назначен?

Comment: Этот код сам по себе ничего такого не делает. Возможно, другой код отслеживает изменения и выполняет какие-то действия. Чтобы можно было разобраться в Вашей ситуации, постройте [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @АндрейNOP не уверен в этом... В Windows Forms я только один день, просто зашёл исправить один баг

Comment: @АндрейNOP я предполагаю что должна быть какая то возможность выбрать элемент из списка.

Comment: @АндрейNOP сейчас как раз ищу =)

Comment: А какова задача? Для чего нужно это делать. Просто если вам просто нужно отметь первый элемент при появлении списка, а дальше как и раньше, то вы просто может поставить переменную типа bool. Сделать её по умолчанию true. Потом отметить элемент и в обработчике проверить если переменная true то поставить false и выйти из него ничего не делая